# How to convert Image to Memory stream?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin. I am designing an application in which we are using SignaturePad. The signature is converting to byte using memory stream and is working fine in Android.But in IOS i am getting exception Specified cast not valid or Invalid cast Exception.Below is  the code i implemented.

SignaturepadView.Xaml code:

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="Center">
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <signature:SignaturePadView x:Name="padView" 
                                 Grid.Row="0" 
                                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                 HeightRequest="100" 
                                 WidthRequest="240"
                                 BackgroundColor="#887e70"
                                 PromptText=""
                                 CaptionText=""
                                 PromptTextColor="Red"
                                 StrokeColor="#ece6dd" 
                                 StrokeWidth="3" />
      <Button Grid.Row="1" 
              Grid.Column="0" 
              Text="Save Signature" 
              Clicked="OnSaveClicked"/>
      <Button Grid.Row="1" 
              Grid.Column="1" 
              Text="Clear" 
              Clicked="OnClearClicked"/>
</Grid>
```

In Xaml.cs

```
private async void OnSaveClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var format = SignatureImageFormat.Png;
     var image = await padView.GetImageStreamAsync(format);`
     var signatureMemoryStream = (MemoryStream)image;
     byte[] data = signatureMemoryStream.ToArray();
     DependencyService.Get<IPicture>().SavePictureToDisk("signimage", data);
}
```

This is working fine in Android.But i am getting exception Specified cast not valid or Invalid cast Exception for IOS. Am i doing anything wrong?. Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Note: I installed package https://components.xamarin.com/view/signature-pad in PCL,Android and IOS as well. Sorry for my English.

Comment: which specific line is causing the exception?  What are the types of the objects you are attempting to cast?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jason.I got exception at var signatureMemoryStream = (MemoryStream)image;....I Solved it by changing the line as...

var ms = new MemoryStream();
            image.CopyTo(ms);

It is working fine in android but i m not able to see anything in IOS.Event it is not throwing any exception.On Debugging i am getting Byte array of image.But it is not storing in Photos..Please help me.

Comment: if it works on one platform but not the other, the problem is most likely in your DependencyService

Comment: Yes I Understood.I gone through http://www.goxuni.com/668633-how-to-save-an-image-to-a-device-using-xuni-and-xamarin-forms/ and implemented the same.But I am getting nothing in Photos.What might be the reason ?

Comment: Are you sure your iOS IPicture code is being called?  Have you stepped through it to verify what it is doing?

Comment: yes. It is called.After calling I added a Display Alert for conformation.On Debug DispalyAlert is not gtting hit.

Comment: public void SavePictureToDisk(string filename, byte[] imageData)
        {
            var chartImage = new UIImage(NSData.FromArray(imageData));
            chartImage.SaveToPhotosAlbum((image, error) =>
            {
            
                if(error != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(error.ToString());
                }
            });
        }

This is what i used as dependency service.Debug is not moving beyond chartImage.SaveToPhotosAlbum((image, error) =>....And in return app is getting crashed/stopped.